# What is the correct way to get fb_ref in an open graph action?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-opengraph

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publish-action/), if you call an open graph action publish with the optional "ref" parameter filled in (let's say, ref: foo), Facebook will return that value to you in the fb_ref URL parameter that Facebook sends your clickers too (let's say, myObject?fb_ref=foo).

However, Facebook is NOT doing this. I haven't seen any yield from including the ref parameter in my action publishes, even on a production, non-sandbox app.

From my experimenting, the only way to get fb_ref into my URL is to include fb_ref in the URL parameters for the object the user is acting upon (rather than by including parameter in the API call), and have the page include that fb_ref in the og:url. However, I'm guessing that this will result in Facebook treating every different fb_ref as a different objects. This is obviously not desirable.

So, no matter what I do, I can't get Facebook to provide a link to anything other than what the og:url in my object specifies and what Facebook generates, such as fb_source.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: same issue here. not only is the fb_ref parameter missing, but all other facebook-generated values are missing on open graph actions every where except when viewing the action in the 'detailed' view (when clicking on the timestamp of the action to view it alone on its own page).